# Cannot read response returned from volley

Tags: android, android-volley, android-handler

I am using volley to get some data from a web service. I'm using the following format to read responses from volley.

I make volley requests calling methods which are defined like below and I show a `progressDialog` when the volley request happens.

```
public static void GetDetails(String tag, Handler handler,
        String Token,String TID){
    String url = "http://myWebserviceMethod"

    JsonArrayRequest jsArrRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            ResponseListener.<JSONArray> createGenericReqSuccessListener(
                    handler, Constant.MessageState.SUCCESS),
            ResponseListener.createErrorListener(handler,
                    Constant.MessageState.FAILED));

    jsArrRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    jsArrRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(2 * 1000, 3, 1.0f));
    MyGlobalClass.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsArrRequest);
}
```

I have a generic response listener which will return me a constant and the response like below

```
public class ResponseListener<T> {

public static <T> Response.Listener<T> createGenericReqSuccessListener(
        final Handler handler, final int messageId) {
    return new Response.Listener<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(T response) {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.arg1 = messageId;
            msg.obj = response;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    };
}

public static Response.ErrorListener createErrorListener(
        final Handler handler, final int messageId) {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.arg1 = messageId;
            msg.obj = error;
            error.printStackTrace();
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    };
}
```

and I'm reading/parsing the responses in the activity using `Handlers` in the following way

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

        switch (msg.arg1) {
        case Constant.MessageState.SUCCESS: // Constant declared in a public class
            parseSaveResponse((JSONArray) msg.obj);
            break;

        case Constant.MessageState.FAILED: // Constant declared in a public class
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            ShowError((VolleyError) msg.obj);
            break;
}
```

It works fine but some times the message never goes to the `handler` and none of the cases are satisfied, leaving me with the `progressDialog` endlessly loading.

What could be the reason behind this?

Looking forward for some leads on this. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling a Google map and a volley service together in the same thread.

Called the web service like below and it worked.

```
map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            //volley web service request.
        }
});
```